# How to show custom error message for @ResponseStatus errors?

Tags: java, spring, spring-rest

I created a custom `@ResponseStatus` exception, and want it both being returned as a json response of a `@RestController`, and also the response payload.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class BadRequestException extends NestedRuntimeException {
    public BadRequestException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

I have a `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` that should log the response after it has been send. Therefore the filter reads `wrapper.getContentAsByteArray()`:

```
public class CustomLoggingFilter extends CommonsRequestLoggingFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseToUse = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);

        try {
            super.doFilterInternal(request, responseToUse, filterChain);
        } finally {
            byte[] buf = responseToUse.getContentAsByteArray();
            String message;

            //PROBLEM: buf.length() == 0 in error case, thus cannot create the message
            LOGGER.info("Response: " + message);
        }
    }
}
```

In general the loggings works, but in case of a `@ResponseStatus` error, the response body/payload is lost!

Question: how can I keep the body payload for logging during an exception?

Comment: You can return your particular `ResponseEntity<>` isn't it enough?

Comment: I haven't played too much in this area of Spring, but thinking if you put `super.doFilterInternal(request, responseToUse, filterChain);` in a catch block as well, after any other stuff you need to do?

Comment: `ResponseEntity` is not known at this stage. Of course the exceptional json body is returned successfully by the `@RestController` to the user. The problem is that the body/buffer is then empty, and cannot be read again for logging. In spite of non-error responses where it works just as written above.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ResponseStatus.  You can think of using ExceptionHandler.

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {..}

Comment: Well but I'd like to explicit define my own exceptions having a `@ResponseStatus` on them, nor further ExceptionHandler explicit...